# Disable Assertions in Android Studio run configuration

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to disable Assertions in Android Studio for a run configuration?

I tried adding `-da` to the `install flags` however it just spit out

```bash
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -da --skip-verification -S 31219503' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument expected after "-da"
```

when I tried to run it.